# Adding Text in pdf using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, scorm

I have a SCORM compliant course where only PDFs are to be shown. I want to show the user name to be populated in the PDF using JavaScript whenever user launches the PDF from LMS.

Please Suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to determine the name of the user, because the system does not really know it. The closest you can use automatically would be the login name of the user.

There is a JavaScript property which represents the login name of the user. However, for privacy reasons, this property is only accessible when Acrobat/Reader starts up. In order to make it available for the document, you'd have to install an application-level script which would read out the login name and make it available in a (global) variable. This is rather impractical and only possible if you have control over your user's machine.

An alternative is a bit kludgy, but would work, is to create an annotation (for example freetext), and display the author property of the annotation. If not changed elsewhere, this would be the login name.

Another approach would be showing a app.answer() dialog where the user has to enter the name, and then you can fill that answer into the text fields where you want it to appear.

Comment: The question mentioned this is a SCORM course, which means the learner's name is stored in cmi.learner_name (see http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference) and is trivial to get. I assume that what the OP is asking is "I have a variable in JavaScript - how do I display it on the PDF?"

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. Is there anything which can be done to achieve it?

Comment: The issue is that Acrobat JavaScript is extremely well sandboxed, so that it is almost impossible to expose it to the outside world to get such an external value. Not knowing SCORM, there might be another way, if SCORM would allow it, namely writing the user's name in the Metadata of the PDF, and from there, it could also be retrieved.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I just want to know if I can add user_name as PDF metadata from a javascript?

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I dont think it is possible to do it with PDFs. I am trying my luck with HTML forms.

Comment: Thanks. But then, why do you ask for a PDF-based solution if you prefer to believe than to know?